# In Acts 9:28, what is the meaning of "coming in and going out" (NKJV)?

Tags: acts, paul, worship

In Acts 9:26-28, we read (NKJV, emphasis mine):

> And when Saul had come to Jerusalem, he tried to join the disciples; but they were all afraid of him, and did not believe that he was a disciple. But Barnabas took him and brought him to the apostles. And he declared to them how he had seen the Lord on the road, and that He had spoken to him, and how he had preached boldly at Damascus in the name of Jesus. So he was with them at Jerusalem, **coming in and going out**.

What does "coming in and going out" (NKJV) refer to? (Apparently, the Byzantine text, as opposed to the TR and NU text, omits "and going out.") Is it a reference to Saul assembling with the disciples for worship, or some other meaning?

Answer (score 3):

The BLB renders Acts 9:28 as -

> And he was **coming in and going out** with them in Jerusalem,
> speaking boldly in the name of the Lord.

The "coming in and going out" is simple Hebrew Idiom for "moving about freely" as is thus translated by several versions:

- NIV: So Saul stayed with them and **moved about freely** in Jerusalem, speaking boldly in the name of the Lord.
- BSB: So Saul stayed with them, **moving about freely** in Jerusalem and speaking boldly in the name of the Lord.
- NASB: And he was with them, **moving about freely** in Jerusalem, speaking out boldly in the name of the Lord.
- CEV: Saul **moved about freely** with the followers in Jerusalem and told everyone about the Lord.
- GNT: And so Saul stayed with them and **went all over** Jerusalem, preaching boldly in the name of the Lord.
- ISV: So he **freely circulated** among them in Jerusalem, speaking courageously in the name of the Lord.
- NAB: He **moved about freely** with them in Jerusalem, and spoke out boldly in the name of the Lord.

The Robinson-Pierpont Byzantine text (2005) has only "going in" but also places "going out" in the margin suggesting that witness of the Byzantine MSS is divided.  For more details about which MSS support which reading, see NA28.

However, I notice that, contrary to the Byzantine and majority texts, the F35 (Pickering) and Orthodox/Apostolic texts include, "going out and coming in".